# Symfony 4 how to specify base path that does not change with the current URL?

Tags: javascript, symfony

in symfony I have a script that changes my icon to another by updating the icon image file source located at `asset/image.png` but this only works on the homepage `mysite.com`.

If I go to another page with `mysite.com/foo` the file is 404 showing wrong path like this `foo/asset/image.png`

Why is it appending `foo` to the image source path ? How can I fix it please ?

I need a way to specify a base path that does not change with the current url

```
function foo(){
  $("#foo").fadeToggle(fadeSpeed, function () {
      $("#foo").attr("src", "/asset/image.png")
  })
}
```

Comment: Set absolute path `/asset/image.png`

Comment: @DawidZbiński tried a million times, that does not work in symfony

Comment: You need to provide us some more information. That's not enough info to specify what can be wrong, unfortunately.

Comment: @DawidZbiński something to do with symfony.. I can't think of any other info to provide that could be useful; if you need something tell me. I need a way to specify a base path that does not change with the current url

Comment: well, absolute paths are not changing if you change a directory. It weird that does not work for you. Are you sure that you added `/` at the beginning of the path?

Comment: @DawidZbiński It is weird right ? must be a symfony setting somewhere... Only having this issue with symfony... yes I am 10000% sure, updated the path in the question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had no asset management system installed.

Everything was solved after installing [asset](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html) `composer require symfony/asset`.